# Make jquery autocomplete not to fill the input value with the label of selected item

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

Is there any way to make jquery autocomplete plugin only respond to the "select" callback, not to fill the target input with the label value of the selected item after user selection?

I am trying but still no success, waiting for help...

Regards.
Larry

Comment: didn't get u properly. means u want that input box should be filled up only by up and down arrow of popup (suggested) data?

Comment: I just found that what I need to do is to clear the box at the end of the "selected: function( event, ui ) " function at line 174 in jquery.ui.autocomplete.js

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[**DEMO ON JS FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/34fSg/6/)

```
$('#ac').autocomplete({
    source : ["hello", "how", "do", "you", "do"],
    select: function(event, ui){
        setTimeout(function (){
          $('#ac').val('');    
        }, 1000)
    }
})
```

Comment: setting my input box in "select" callback like: $('#autocomplete').val(''); seems not working

Comment: this is not error-proof, it's just a work around. you should have used `event.preventDefault();` and then added your custom actions.

Answer (score 11):

I know that this is an old question but, for people that doesn't want to use the setTimeout function, the solution is to change the property ui.item.value to ""

**Code**:

```
$('#ac').autocomplete({
    source : ["hello", "how", "do", "you", "do"],
    select: function(event, ui){
        if (ui.item && ui.item.value){
            ui.item.value="";
        } 
    }
})
```

Comment: Sometimes it may be preferable to set `ui.item.value = ui.item.label` depending on what you need. This will show the label in the input box, rather than an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

Try code below ;)

```
$('#ac').autocomplete({
    source : ["hello", "how", "do", "you", "do"],
    close: function(event, ui){
          $('#ac').val('');
    }
});
```

Comment: Use $(event.target).val(''); instead.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an even simpler way (using experimentX's code):

```
$('#ac').autocomplete({
    source : ["hello", "how", "do", "you", "do"],
    select: function(event, ui){
        $('#ac').css('color','white');    
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If your source array is an array of objects with "label" and "value" properties, the plugin handles this for you.

See[jQuery api for autocomplete](https://api.jqueryui.com/1.8/autocomplete/#option-source):

```js
$('#autocomplete').autocomplete({
    source: [
      {
        label: 'This is a descriptive label'
        , value: 'Just the value'
      }
      ,{
        label: '2 is better than one'
        , value: '2'}
      ,{
        label: 'third times the charm'
        , value:'Three'
      }
    ]
  })
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.js"></script>
<input type='text' id='autocomplete'>
```

SO's code snippet doesn't like it but it works